# AvgExpression error in seurat: invalid name for slot of class “Assay5”: check.matrix

Tags: heatmap, seurat

I am trying to generate a heatmap for specific genes in my single cell dataset but I keep getting a weird error. I have previously generated a heatmap with this code before for the same dataset.

This is my code for average expression:

```
x <- AverageExpression(x, assays = NULL, return.seurat = TRUE)
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Counts matrix provided is not sparse. Creating V5 assay in Seurat Object.
Error in initialize(value, ...) : 
  invalid name for slot of class “Assay5”: check.matrix
```